# How do I download a page with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I did not find a solution how to download a whole Webpage
All I want is to navigate to 
 https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/ManuelNotManni?
and download it. Is it possible to download the page with Selenium?
I used the following Code to navigate to the page:

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(".", options))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/ManuelNotManni?");                
}
```

Comment: Code trials to download the page?

Comment: And what do you mean by "download"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: Also, why do you need Selenium? That is a publically accessible JSON file. Just use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) class, and then parse it as JSON using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Yes I have had it with a webclient before but the Api I want do download has inserted a filter. So it is not possible to download it on this way. My friend recommended me to try selenium because cloudflare (the filters name) will propably not detect it. With "download" I mean to Copy that text or in best case to parse it as JSON as you wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the page source content with `driver.PageSource` command. And save it to the file.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(".", options))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/ManuelNotManni?");   
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync("PageSource.html", driver.PageSource);       
}
```

For downloading json it will work well.

But for html pages, note:

> If the page has been modified after loading (for example, by JavaScript) there is no guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.

---

**References**

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver_PageSource.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file